# Como puedo sacar el HTML de la siguiente peticion web?

Tags: c#, html, post

```
string html = "";

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string address = "https://#.tk/index-post.php";
    byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("name=wololo");
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webClient.UploadData(address, postData);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo sacar el código HTML de la página cuando hace la petición `POST`?

Comment: Las peticiones `POST` no tienen por qué devolver algo. Lo más normal es que la respuesta HTTP de una petición POST solo contenga cabeceras, para indicar que todo está bien, pero no cuerpo (es decir, no contenido), o puede que ni siquiera conteste, excepto para terminar la conexión TCP (que no serían paquetes HTTP). Además, una petición HTTP puede devolver lo que sea, cualquier pieza de texto o binaria, no necesariamente HTML. Podría devolver un texto en formato json o xml, o una imagen (respuesta binaria), por ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

La documentación del método ya te da una pista

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tdbbwh0a(v=vs.110).aspx

El método devuelve un `byte[]` con la respuesta del servidor, y si ya sabes que es un HTML, puedes transformarlo en un string:

```
byte[] responseArray = myWebClient.UploadData(uriString,postArray);

string htmlString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que aquí hay una pregunta similar, pero en el stackoverflow en inglés, aquí te dejo el [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post), espero que te sirva

Después sí lo que quieres es leer el html en específico aquí te dejo un método:

```
string html = "";
using( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( @"c:\index.html" ) )
{
 String line = String.Emtpy;
 while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null )
 {
    html += line;
 }
}
```

Aquí dejo el [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/060ea8e0-cc63-44a3-b0dc-b531c29b8a0f/read-html-content-using-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral) de donde aparece ese ejemplo